# Should I push compiled javascript or ignore them?

Tags: git, angular, typescript

In the new Angular 2 we were introduced to TypeScript which primarily provides optional static typing, classes and interfaces.

After writing in TypeScript we are required to compile the code to JavaScript in order to run the program

The question is should I push the compiled javascript to the server with the typescript files or should I ignore javascript files on `.gitignore` and just run `npm start` on the server which will compile the files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your source code are the typescript files. The build artifacts are the javascript files which gets deployed to the server. So only the source code (typescript files) should be checked-in and ignore the transpiled javascripts files.