# Should compiled JavaScript files be committed to Git repo?

Tags: javascript, git, typescript

New to TypeScript here and just wondering what the community views as best practice.

When I compile for production, I use the webpack loader. However, when I run my tests, I need to run `tsc && ava`. This generates a `.js` equivalent file in the same location as their `.ts` counterparts. Should these by committed to the repo alongside the `.ts` files? My first assumption is no because they should be re-compiled each time before a process e.g. *starting your server or executing tests* is run. However, I'd just like to get the community's opinion on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When coding in TypeScript should the generated .js files be committed to git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090904/when-coding-in-typescript-should-the-generated-js-files-be-committed-to-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41136840/should-i-push-compiled-javascript-or-ignore-them

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your assumption is absolutely correct - build artefacts and outputs shouldn't be added to your repository. The main reason for this is that it's easy to end up in a situation where the source `.ts` file has changed but the compiled `.js` file differs because it's not been committed at the same time.

You also add complexity to your pull-requests/merge reviews, as there will be a large amount of generated code that isn't *really* part of the review but is in the changeset.

Finally, merging changes becomes a bit of a pain, because you need to recompile the `.js` files for every merge you do.

If you *only* use `.ts` files in your source directory, you can add `/**/*.js` to your `.gitignore` to prevent files from being added accidentally.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the detailed answer and the gitignore suggestion :)

Comment: There's a caveat, if you are building a npm package with typescript and using git to host a private npm registry you will definitely want to commit the compiled `.js` files and their type definitions.

Comment: @TemporaryFix that's a good point, npm also allows you to install a package from Github `npm install profile-name/package#branch` if you don't have the build artifact it won't reflect the same behavior as installing published version from npmjs.com

Comment: @TemporaryFix could you please elaborate on why we need push compiled files to host a  private npm registry

Comment: @saiamar Typescript can't natively be executed