# GitHub Desktop won't detect changes when I make a build apk?

Tags: android, git, github

I'm building a voice recording app and right now I'm backing up all of my code to GitHub and a memory stick.  Whenever I make it build it saves it into the file directory that GitHub desktop it's backing up,  but it won't detect some of my files. Such as: app.iml and app-debug.apk.

Has anyone else had this problem and if you have fixed it could you tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files shouldn't be committed or relied on since you will need to rebuild the project anyway when you do a fresh checkout. Your code might be different than your compiled code depending of how you added them. Check out this thread that talks about javascript  [Should compiled JavaScript files be committed to Git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50796326/should-compiled-javascript-files-be-committed-to-git-repo)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Git ignoring files and directories specified in the .gitignore file in the root of your repository directory.

See lines from one of my repositories:

`*.iml
..
..
/build`

Your apk file is just the latest build of your code, so the source code saved to GitHub is the backup.

Comment: my repo has no .gitignore file

Comment: @NathanBendall It may not be added to the repo on GitHub but in the directory on your computer, or might also be a hidden file, depending on setup.
The main point stands though; your source code will always allow you to generate a fresh apk. See also tiborK's answer above as well.